# How to get Reddit comments based on (post_id , comment_id) only?

Tags: comments, extract, reddit

I have a file containing (post_ids,comment_ids). How can I extract the Reddit comments based on those two columns only? I don't have any other informations like SubReddit_name,url etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the comment data using just the comment id. You can use the Reddit API to get the full comment JSON object. Here's an [example](https://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?id=t1_hcve9uq) of how to do it. I recommend implementing a rate limiter on top of it so you don't get blacklisted (or alternatively use a tool like [this](https://redditbests.com/tools/comment-extractor/?id=hcve9uq) that has rate limiting built in.

When passing comment ids to the Reddit API make sure to prepend them with the `t1_` prefix. So if the comment id is `hcve9uq`, you will be passing `t1_hcve9uq`.

Example of Reddit API results for a given comment id:

`GET https://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?id=t1_hcve9uq`

```
{
   "kind":"Listing",
   "data":{
      "after":null,
      "dist":1,
      "modhash":"fy7jn1i12yf3857a406ac27f7cf265489515da1f41d290f770",
      "geo_filter":"",
      "children":[
         {
            "kind":"t1",
            "data":{
               "total_awards_received":0,
               "approved_at_utc":null,
               "author_is_blocked":false,
               "comment_type":null,
               "edited":false,
               "mod_reason_by":null,
               "banned_by":null,
               "author_flair_type":"richtext",
               "removal_reason":null,
               "link_id":"t3_pobe0r",
               "author_flair_template_id":null,
               "likes":null,
               "replies":"",
               "author_fullname":"t2_b9q002jq",
               "saved":false,
               "id":"hcve9uq",
               "banned_at_utc":null,
               "mod_reason_title":null,
               "gilded":0,
               "archived":false,
               "collapsed_reason_code":null,
               "no_follow":false,
               "author":"Ermingardia",
               "can_mod_post":false,
               "created_utc":1631654752.0,
               "send_replies":true,
               "parent_id":"t1_hcvdmlw",
               "score":395,
               "approved_by":null,
               "author_premium":false,
               "mod_note":null,
               "all_awardings":[
                  
               ],
               "subreddit_id":"t5_2wlj3",
               "body":"Yes, I seriously disturbed his crypto signals!",
               "awarders":[
                  
               ],
               "user_reports":[
                  
               ],
               "author_flair_css_class":"Training",
               "name":"t1_hcve9uq",
               "author_patreon_flair":false,
               "downs":0,
               "author_flair_richtext":[
                  {
                     "e":"text",
                     "t":"Redditor for 6 months."
                  }
               ],
               "is_submitter":true,
               "body_html":"&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Yes, I seriously disturbed his crypto signals!&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;",
               "gildings":{
                  
               },
               "collapsed_reason":null,
               "distinguished":null,
               "associated_award":null,
               "stickied":false,
               "can_gild":true,
               "top_awarded_type":null,
               "author_flair_text_color":"dark",
               "score_hidden":false,
               "permalink":"/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/pobe0r/crypto_scammer_got_in_touch_with_me_he_didnt_know/hcve9uq/",
               "num_reports":null,
               "locked":false,
               "report_reasons":null,
               "created":1631654752.0,
               "subreddit":"CryptoCurrency",
               "author_flair_text":"Redditor for 6 months.",
               "treatment_tags":[
                  
               ],
               "collapsed":false,
               "subreddit_name_prefixed":"r/CryptoCurrency",
               "controversiality":0,
               "author_flair_background_color":"",
               "collapsed_because_crowd_control":null,
               "mod_reports":[
                  
               ],
               "subreddit_type":"public",
               "ups":395
            }
         }
      ],
      "before":null
   }
}
```